# appending a list that you are iterating over with a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

somebody mentioned that the function (in this case a method) below is no good as it modifies a list while iterating over it. Why is this, as it works exactly as I intended. I was actually quite pleased with it...  Is there a better way of writing it.

Data structures, function and output as follows:

```
nodes = { ('foo','bar',1),
          ('foo','baz',1),
          ('baz','gad',0),
          ('boo','moo',1),
          ('goo','loo',0),
          ('bar','far',1),
          ('far','aaa',0) }

class Graph(dict):

    def __missing__(self, key):
        self[key] = set()
        return self[key]

    def add_node_pairs(self, node_pairs):
        for pair in node_pairs:
            nodeA, nodeB, weight = pair
            self[nodeA].add((weight, nodeB))
            self[nodeB].add((weight, nodeA)) 

    def find_paths(self, keys):      
        paths = [(key,) for key in keys if key in self]
        for path in paths:
            *oldkeys, key = path
            for weight, next_key in self[key]:
                if next_key not in oldkeys:
                    paths.append( path + (weight,next_key) )

        paths.sort()
        return paths

graph = Graph()
graph.add_node_pairs(nodes)
print(graph)
print( graph.find_paths(['foo']))
```

---

graph:

```
{ 'goo': {(0, 'loo')}, 
  'foo': {(1, 'bar'), (1, 'baz')}, 
  'aaa': {(0, 'far')}, 
  'far': {(1, 'bar'), (0, 'aaa')}, 
  'baz': {(0, 'gad'), (1, 'foo')}, 
  'loo': {(0, 'goo')}, 
  'moo': {(1, 'boo')}, 
  'boo': {(1, 'moo')}, 
  'bar': {(1, 'far'), (1, 'foo')}, 
  'gad': {(0, 'baz')} }
```

find_paths ('foo'):

```
[ ('foo',), 
  ('foo', 1, 'bar'), 
  ('foo', 1, 'bar', 1, 'far'), 
  ('foo', 1, 'bar', 1, 'far', 0, 'aaa'), 
  ('foo', 1, 'baz'), 
  ('foo', 1, 'baz', 0, 'gad') ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the three following examples:

```
l = [1]
for x in l:
    if x < 10 # avoid infinite loop
         l.append(x+1)
    print x
```

This code is correct and is similar to the one you are using. The output is as expected 1..10.
Appending an item on a for loop is ok (or inserting an item after the current iterator position).

Now try the same example but with an insert instead:

```
l = [1]
for x in l:
    if x < 10 # avoid infinite loop
         l.insert(0,x+1)
    print x
```

This time, you'll end up with a infinite loop. The reason is that the for loop will always check the next item and since we are inserting x at the beginning, the checked item will always be equal to 1. Inserting an item prior to the current iterator position is usually bad.

Finally check this example:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5]
for x in l:
     print x
     l.remove(x)
```

The output of this function will be 1,3,5 different from the expected output: 1,2,3,4,5.
Therefor, removing items before the current iterator is also bad.

To simplify things, let's just say that changing the content of a list while looping should be avoided, unless you know exactly what you are doing and what effects it could cause on the output.

Comment: I think your first example will infinitely loop, your are appending 1 each time and testing it against being less than 10. if it was `l.append(x + 1)` it would work

Comment: @ThemanontheClaphamomnibus This is not even proper code, there are missing `:`, but it gets the idea through. However, how come OP's code doesn't go into an infinite loop?

Comment: @jadkik94, it is because the list is only extended if the last value of the tuple that the for loop is iterating over is in the dictionary. If not, then nothing is added. As the dictionary is finite, and as the values are not allowed to appear twice in one tuple, the for loop can not be infinite

Comment: @ThemanontheClaphamomnibus That makes sense, so you do have a good reason to do what you're doing :)

Comment: well, I think so... but when people claim that it is 'bad practice' I do try to listen... as long as pythonistas don't start making voodoo dolls of me.. I'm happy!

Answer (score 2):

Appending to a list you are iterating over is safe.  If your code reviewer won't accept that, or it still feels squishy to you, you can use a two-phase approach:

```
paths = [blah blah]
next_paths = []
while paths:
    for path in paths:
        if something_or_other:
            next_paths.append(blah)
    paths = next_paths
    next_paths = []
```